# What should I work with to get the file via a httprequest (from my frontend) + its url in phpmyadmin (MYSQL)?

Tags: c#, mysql, parse-platform

Should I work with a longblob with a varchar next to it with the url? And in my varchar give a URL-link from my localhost/Image.jpg?

When I work with a backend called "parse" I recieved it like this:

```
"filename": "tfss-0f79045d-bade-4098-a16a-f11d08ewqwq3c9013-drick1.jpg",
"url": "http://files.parsetfss.com/651wqb49a1-157a-4f92-8d52-9ceefe77ca46/tfss-0f79wq045d-badwqe-4wq098-a16a-f11d083c9013-test.jpg"
```

And I would like to have it similiar here as I am used to work with that.
When I take it out in my frontend code I would solve it with something like this:

```
var myPicture = "";
if(currentItem["myImage"] != null)
{
prodPic = (string) ["myImage"] ["url"];
}
```

Is a longblob + varchar with the URL (localhost/Image.jpg) the way to go if I want to work with it as I did with parse?

Answer (score 0):

You must try it in c#:

```
var myPicture = "";
if(currentItem["myImage"] != null)
{
    prodPic = await currentItem.Get<ParseFile>("myImage").Url;
}
```